# Stomp Consumer using deferred.inlinecallback

Tags: python, stomp

I am implementing stomp consumer as a library. By calling this library in other application i should be able to get the data in ActiveMQ. I am implementing it as below, but I have a problem in returning the frame.body. I am not able to retrieve the data from outside the class.

```
 from twisted.internet import defer
 from stompest.async import Stomp
 from stompest.async.listener import SubscriptionListener
 from stompest.config import StompConfig
 from socket import gethostname
 from uuid import uuid1

 import json

 class Consumer(object):
      def __init__(self, amq_uri):
          self.amq_uri = amq_uri
          self.hostname = gethostname()
          self.config = StompConfig(uri=self.amq_uri)


     @defer.inlineCallbacks
     def run(self, in_queue):
         client = yield Stomp(self.config)
         headers = {
            StompSpec.ACK_HEADER: StompSpec.ACK_CLIENT_INDIVIDUAL,
            StompSpec.ID_HEADER: self.hostname,
            'activemq.prefetchSize': '1000',
           }

         yield client.connect(headers=self._return_client_id())
         client.subscribe(
               in_queue,
               headers,
               listener=SubscriptionListener(self.consume)
               )

         try:
           client = yield client.disconnected
         except StompConnectionError:
           yield client.connect(headers=self._return_client_id())
           client.subscribe(
               in_queue,
               headers,
               listener=SubscriptionListener(self.consume)
                )

           while True:
               try:
                  yield client.disconnected
               except StompProtocolError:
                  pass
               except StompConnectionError:
                  yield client.connect(headers=self._return_client_id())
              client.subscribe(
                       in_queue,
                       headers,
                       listener=SubscriptionListener(self.consume)
                       )

         def _return_client_id(self):
             client_id = {}
             client_id['client-id'] = gethostname() + '-' + str(uuid1())
             return client_id

        def consume(self, client, frame):
             data = json.loads(frame.body)
             print 'Received Message Type {}'.format(type(data))
             print 'Received Message {}'.format(data)
             ## I want to return data here. I am able to print the frame.body here.


       # Call from another application
          import Queue
          from twisted.internet import reactor

          amq_uri = 'tcp://localhost:61613'
          in_queue = '/queue/test_queue'

          c = Consumer(amq_uri)
          c.run(in_queue)
          print "data is from outside function", data   # Should be able to get the data which is returned by consume here
          reactor.run()
```

Can someone please let me know how can i achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Instead of using async stomp library, i used sync stomp library. Implemented it as below,

```
 class Consumer(object):
    def __init__(self, amq_uri):
        self.amq_uri = amq_uri
        self.hostname = gethostname()
        self.config = StompConfig(uri=self.amq_uri)

    def run(self, in_queue, return_dict):
        client = Stomp(self.config)
        headers = {
         StompSpec.ACK_HEADER: StompSpec.ACK_CLIENT_INDIVIDUAL,
         StompSpec.ID_HEADER: self.hostname
          }
         client.connect()
         client.subscribe(in_queue, headers)
         try:
             frame = client.receiveFrame()
             data = json.dumps(frame.body)
         except Exception as exc:
             print exc
         client.ack(frame)
         client.disconnect()
         return_dict['data'] = data
         return data
```